# What is the correct way to appeal to authority as a Computer Scientist/Engineer?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, behavior

For the moment, I'm a solo software and computer engineer working for a startup. I don't get to work with other engineers a lot, because I have only been out of school for four years and still going back for a Masters in AI I started, but could not move on in school until I get my massive Embedded C++1x SDK finished.

So I can't say that I am an expert, but there are a lot of situations on Stack Overflow where I do have some credibility in Embedded-C++1x and I have a good answer, but I have a very low reputation and there is a lot of bad C++ advice from years of bad C++ practices and I'm not the best at debating and sometimes I come off like a jerk when rebutting arguments with older engineers and a lot of the younger engineers are all beat up from school trauma and are traumatized about their Stack Overflow reputation. I'm a kind, loving person who is just opinionated. I like these people/friends, and I want my written words to come off as intended but they don't.

This has caused some problem with me on Slack channels from criticising Apple programming languages at school and Facebook. At school, I had some issues with a teammate not being willing to try Visual Studio (VS) in Windows and it caused me to get a bad grade in an important Software Engineering (CS300) class, because they tried to last minute it and couldn't get VS working. I then proceeded to go on the CS Slack channel and criticise Apple programming tools, because they are not cross-platform and I said "you're a fool for not programming cross-platform software" and I said "I've been programming C++ software for over a decade" and blah blah blah and this really made the Apple users mad and they booted me off the CS Slack channel, which is a State-funded channel and I was banned by students earning State funds for tutoring, violating my Free Speech. On Facebook I just sounded like a jerk anytime I said I was an engineer to gain reputability in politics and I had to delete my profile because of trolls constantly attacking me. People really hate it when you talk about your degree(s).

This is causing problems for me and I need to be more respectful, because I'm not a jerk and these are my friends and colleagues, and I like my C++ SDK too much to change careers. Do I need some advice on how Appeal to Authority to use my education and work experience on Stack Overflow without sounding like a jerk or flaming any other programmers who are likely to argue with me for hours? Is it best to just never talk about my education and just insert links to proof? What are the ways that you have convinced others of your side (**@note** I did not say *win the argument*)?

Comment: I think we need a TLDR, or a rewording. It's difficult to tell what's being asked here. Is this about Stack Exchange?

Comment: c++ dev crapping on other languages... Oh, the irony.

Comment: "People really hate it when you talk about your degree(s)." - Yes, Yes we do.

Comment: Now I can't ask a question on StackOverflow from you people.  I deleted all my accounts, I really do hate interacting on these sites. I've loved programming all my life being an engineer has been miserable. The people don't act right, and they are all viciously mean if you challenge what they say. Me personally I'm pretty forgiving, loving, and kind, but other people have been so disrespectful of me as a human for being an engineer. They hate you for being successful, and I'm not even successful. I hate how people control what you say and kick ou out of the town square for having an opinion.

Comment: I hate how you people suppress criticism because you want to be in a bubble where you only hear nice things. This isn't a town square, this is an authoritarian dictatorship where you have no free speech and people attack you and if you dare say you have credentials they'll insult you. I'm done with that. StackOverflow has been the most miserable site I've ever been on.

Comment: note: "appeal to authority" is [a logical fallacy](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/appeal-to-authority). by intentionally using it you are making your argument weaker, not stronger.

Answer (score 9):

> What is the correct way to appeal to authority as a Computer Scientist/Engineer

**TL;DR;**

You don't, you can't.
That doesn't enhance your posts quality in any way. There's no relevance to your current job position or experience.
Your content posted will be judged here by people who find it useful or not.

A way to show your *authority* is the ability to ask the concise and useful questions (for future research) about a core problem you meet.

If you are not able to do that, you probably have to improve your skills on whatever topic asked.
The fact you just have a job position already, doesn't well leverage your position asking here.

Comment: I'm just going to delete my profile because I'm just not happy with the way people act online because they always have to make big deals about stuff they would not usually do anything about in real life.

Comment: @Cale I don't see what's your problem? This is fairly _real life_.

Comment: @Cale - Except you are doing exactly that, making a big deal, out of stuff you that should not matter.